# Update column value if another column has a certain substring

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I'm facing a lot of trouble on what seems to be a simple matter:

I have a column with some beverages names, but they are poluted with "12oz" and "Boxes". I want to get only the name of the beverages. Unfortunally, they are not typed in the same particular form, so i cant just [0:5] them. I know all the beverages names on the column, if that helps

Ex:
Column name: **WHISKY BALLANTINES12YO 12X1000 ML RESTAGE**

Column Created based on the previous one: **BALLANTINES**

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT**
Some other examples:

**CHIVAS REGAL 12 ANOS 12X1L** should be **CHIVAS**

**VODKA ABSOLUT 12X1000ML** should be **ABSOLUT**

Comment: Could you please add a few more examples? A regular expression might work here...

Comment: Added another examples!

Comment: I made it work using RegEx! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just use replace statements, set regex to true, and replace with an empty string, like this:

```
df.replace('12oz', '', regex=True)
```

This is assuming you know what text you will have to replace.

Comment: Sadly the string poluted part is no the same in every row

Comment: Appreciate the help, imad. RegEx did the job!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of all the beverages, you can use [**`pandas.Series.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
import re
​
list_of_bvr= ["ballantines", "chivas", "absolut"]

df["Col1"]= df["Col1"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(list_of_bvr)})", flags=re.I, expand=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

          Col1
0  BALLANTINES
1       CHIVAS
2      ABSOLUT
```